# How to select a section from a string in using bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have an array containing strings which consist of paths to files in the following format:

**/path/to/file/14561234545_50303.TXT**

I'm trying to select the section that is after the "1" but before the "_", so that it would look like **4561234545**.  I've been trying to do this with sed, but so far haven't been able to get just that section.

Can anyone help give me an example of what expression I would need to pull just that section?

Comment: You have received several answers to your question now. Hopefully they are of use to you. If so, would you mind choosing one of the answers as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your path is stored in a bash variable `path`, 
use bash string strip operator to strip up to the furthest most "/1" characters.
Then awk to print up to the _ char.

> echo ${path##*/1} | awk -F_ '{print $1}'

Comment: the first part seems to work, but when I add the awk part, I'm not getting anything back.  Also, I should mention that I'm trying to assign the output of this to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on all elements of an array:

```
$ paths=( /path/to/file/14561234545_50303.TXT /a/b/1ABCD_foo "/x/y/12 3 4 5_.e_f_g" )
$ new=( "${paths[@]##*/1}" )
$ new=( "${new[@]%%_*}" )
$ printf "%s\n" "${new[@]}"
4561234545
ABCD
2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit underspecified, but here is a short solution using *sed* (you said *sed*, right? ;-))

```
input='/path/to/file/14561234545_50303.TXT'
section=`basename $input | sed 's/^1\([^_]\+\).*/\1/'`
```

Explained:

1. pull the filename with *basename* (I'm guessing you need to perform the extraction only on the filename part)
2. perform a *sed* match as follows:

   1. `^1` : match *1* at the beginning of the string (again, a guess, adapt to your liking)
   2. `\( [^_]\+ \)` : (spaces added for clarity) match a sequence of one or more (`\+`) characters that *do not* match underscore, and save this sequence into `\1`
   3. `.*` : match everything else that follows (starting with the underscore `_` if your input is well-formed)
3. replace the matched text (which is the entire string if your input is well-formed!) with the sequence of non-underscore characters that was extracted in step 2.2

You really need to include `.*` at the end of the match to consume the rest of the input. If you don't, the replacement in step 3 will act *only* on the part of the string leading up to the underscore, and you will be surprised to find your output almost identical to your input, except for the leading `1`.